# Pyspark write in file doesn't not exist

Tags: python, pyspark

I try to write in file in pyspark but I have an error, the file doesn't exist. I'm new in pyspark.

I have this code for write:

```
result.repartition(1).write.partitionBy('client', 'payload_type').json(OUTPUT_PATH, mode='append')
```

Is it possible to add a parameter to force to create folder/file if doesn't exist ?

Comment: I've tried your example and it worked. Could you please include more information, stack trace, errors etc.

Answer (score 1):

I make a mistake, the error is not at the line of the post but this:

```
existing_data = spark.read.json(OUTPUT_PATH)
```

with:

```
OUTPUT_PATH = f"s3a://{BUCKET_DEST}/{SOURCE}/"
```

At the first execution, both folder doesn't exist, can I force create it if no exist on the read?